# Folder Restriction / Allow File Download via PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I blocked direct access to **FILES/** folder using .htaccess with following code

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

Now, files cannot be access via direct link. e.g. http://domain.com/files/anyfile.ext

However, all I want now is that If request is coming through **download.php**

```
header("location: files/link");
```

OR

```
<a href="files/link">Download</a>
```

Then, .htaccess should allow file download (only if referrer is **download.php**

What kind of rule I need to use in .htaccess for it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with php. How have you 'blocked direct access for users' to the folder 'FILES'?

Comment: The Referrer is not reliable in any way, so don’t make the mistake of assuming that this would offer any real protection.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to push the file to the user as shown in these examples from the PHP manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#refsect1-function.readfile-examples

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
   header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
   header('Expires: 0');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
   header('Pragma: public');
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
   ob_clean();
   flush();
   readfile($file);
   exit;
}
?>
```

This will automatically start a file download of the file `monkey.gif` and should initiate the download regardless of the Apache deny settings.

Be sure to check that you're script is accessible and it should work beautifully.

Hope this helps.